# How to read Deep-ocean Assessment and Reporting of Tsunamis (DART®) data in python

Tags: python

I am trying to plot water column height with python from DART data,
http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/dart_deployment_realtime/23228.dart

```
 import pandas as pd
 link = "http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/dart_deployment_realtime/23228.dart"
 data = pd.read_table(link)
```

but data have only one column and I cant access seprated data

> ## Site:                   23228
>
> 0   #Paroscientific Serial: W23228
>   1   #YY  MM DD hh mm ss T   HEIGHT
>   2   #yr  mo dy hr mn  s -        m
>   3   2014 08 08 06 00 00 1 2609.494
>   4   2014 08 08 05 45 00 1 2609.550
>   5   2014 08 08 05 30 00 1 2609.605
>   6   2014 08 08 05 15 00 1 2609.658
>   7   2014 08 08 05 00 00 1 2609.703
>   8   2014 08 08 04 45 00 1 2609.741
>   9   2014 08 08 04 30 00 1 2609.769
>   10  2014 08 08 04 15 00 1 2609.787
>   11  2014 08 08 04 00 00 1 2609.799
>   12  2014 08 08 03 45 00 1 2609.802

for example I just want HEIGHT value as numpy array, I dont know have to access this specific column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure Python (no NumPy) I would use the `csv` module:

```
import urllib2
import csv

u = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/dart_deployment_realtime/23228.dart')
r = csv.reader(r, delimiter=' ')

# skip the headers
for _ in range(3):
    next(r, None)
```

Now `r` contains an iterable which gives one row (list of 8 items) at a time for whatever you need. Of course, if you need a list of lists, you may just do `list(r)`.

---

However, as you are handling rather a large amount of data, you may probably want to use NumPy. In that case:

```
import urllib2
import numpy as np

u = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/dart_deployment_realtime/23228.dart')
arr = np.loadtxt(u, skiprows=3)
```

This gives you an array of 92551 x 8 values.

Accessing the heights as a NumPy array is then simple:

```
arr[:,7]
```

---

Pandas is another possibility, as you correctly thought. It is just a matter of a few parameters...

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd

link = 'http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/dart_deployment_realtime/23228.dart'
df = pd.read_table(link, delimiter=r'\s+', skiprows=[1,3], header=1)
```

Now you have a nice DataFrame with `df["HEIGHT"]` as the height. (The column names are taken from row 2 of the file.)

---

And for the plotting...

```
df["HEIGHT"].plot()
```

creates

[image]

(Then I guess you will ask how to get the proper date on the X axis. I think that is worth a completely new question...)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can modify the following:

```
import urllib2, numpy
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/dart_deployment_realtime/23228.dart')
all_lines = response.read().splitlines()
lines_of_interest = all_lines[4:len(all_lines)]
heights = numpy.zeros(len(lines_of_interest), dtype=float)
for idx, line in enumerate(lines_of_interest):
    heights[idx] = float(line.split()[7])
```

Then:

```
>>> heights.shape
(92551,)

>>> heights
array([ 2609.27 ,  2609.213,  2609.153, ...,  2611.157,  2611.084,
        2611.008])
```

Etc.